# eliminar archivos exe y excluir uno

Tags: windows, cmd, exe

Estoy creando un bat para eliminar todos los archivos .exe de mi escritorio y carpeta de descargas (que a veces se acumulan de tantas descargas)...

```
call:delfiles "*.exe"
exit

:: funcion delfiles
@echo off
pause
goto:eof
:delfiles
 set delfiles=%1
  attrib -h -s -r +a "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\%delfiles%"
  attrib -h -s -r +a "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%delfiles%"
  del /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\%delfiles%"
  del /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%delfiles%"
 goto:eof
```

Pero necesito excluir uno solo "ejemplo.exe" ubicado en estas carpetas. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

But I need to exclude one "example.exe" located in these folders. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar a esconder ese archivo y despues de borrar desocultarlo

```
 ....

 :delfiles
 set delfiles=%1
 attrib -h -s -r +a "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\%delfiles%"
 attrib -h -s -r +a "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%delfiles%"

 ATTRIB +H  tu-ruta/ejemplo.exe
 del /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\%delfiles%"
 del /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%delfiles%"
 ATTRIB -H  tu-ruta/ejemplo.exe

 goto:eof

 ....
```

<sub>Nota: haz una copia primero por si acaso</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ocupar

```
for %i in (*) do if not %i == ejemplo.exe del %i
```

Donde %i es el nombre de cada archivo que itera y lo comparamos con el que NO quieres eliminar

**EDIT**

Ahora logre que funcionara en un .bat

```
for %%i in (%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\%delfiles%) do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="ejemplo.exe" del "%%i"
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47514/discussion-on-answer-by-sioesi-eliminar-archivos-exe-y-excluir-uno).